# Javascript Prompt() only working inline and not in external file

Tags: javascript, html, css, prompt

I have a prompt() variable that only works when it is inside `<script>` tags in the html file, but do to some constraints I can't do that. Instead I have it in a `.js` file, but when I refresh the page it doesn't prompt me. The file is loaded, but nothing happens. Any ideas why this happens?

Updated with code

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" href="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="display">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? (See [mcve]).

Comment: Do you mean `<style>` tag or `<script>` tag? `prompt()` is javascript, not css.

Comment: @shaochuancs Definitely meant `<script>` haha. It's really late here. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'll add the code

Comment: use `src`, not `href` in `<script>`

Comment: @shaochuancs Well that's what I get for coding at 4am. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" href="index.js"></script>
> ```

The attribute you are looking for is `src` not `href`.

Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: I really just shouldn't be coding at 4am. Thank you!